# Breadcrumb displaying "[object name] object" in adminmodel editor

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a new AdminModel in my system, but the breadcrumb is displaying "StatementTemplate object" as the title of the editor page. I just want the breadcrumb to read "Statement Template" but I am not sure what setting on the AdminModel I should set to get this to work

ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The breadcrumb is displaying the name of the object, or what `__str__()` returns on the object. If you edit the model so that `__str__()` returns something more meaningful, that will show up in the admin breadcrumb.

```
# in models.py
class StatementTemplate(models.Model):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return "StatementTemplate" # or make it some description of that particular object
```